# Using namespace MPI; Error : name must be a namespace name

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, namespaces, mpi, using

I was trying to execute an MS MPI program , after I have installed libraries : MPI64 lib and directory : MSMPI_INC. The visual studio keeps telling me that *using namesspace MPI* must be a namespace name. The editor recognize the *#include <mpi.h>* but still has an error with namespace.
Also has another error with matric declaration and DOUBLE type in some cases.
Here is the code :

```
/*
    Shumzimi i matricave.
    A ndahet ne procese dhe B bartet tek te gjithe proceset.

*/

#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    int n, n_local, myrank, nbproc;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nbproc);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank);

    n = a;

    n_local = n / nbproc;

    double matrix_a[n_local][n], matrix_b[n][n], matrix_c[n][n], matrix_a1[n][n], matrix_c1[n_local][n];/*here is the matrix declaration error : *C++ expression must have a constant value
the value of variable (declared at line 18) cannot be used as a constant* */

    if (myrank == 0)
    {
        //matrix a
        cout << "\n" << "   Matrica A " << "\n";
        cout << "--------------" << "\n";

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                matrix_a1[i][j] = rand() % 10;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) cout << matrix_a1[i][j] << "\t";
            cout << endl;
        }
        //matrix b
        cout << "\n" << "   Matrica B " << "\n";
        cout << "--------------" << "\n";

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                matrix_b[i][j] = rand() % 10;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)cout << matrix_b[i][j] << "\t";
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    //dergimi Broadcast te vlerave te matrices B tek te gjithe proceset
    MPI_COMM_WORLD.Bcast(matrix_b, n * n, DOUBLE, 0);/*here is the DOUBLE error*/
    //Mbarimi i Broadcast

    //Shperndarja (scattering) e rreshtave te A ne te gjithe proceset
    MPI_COMM_WORLD.Scatter(matrix_a1, n * n_local, DOUBLE, matrix_a, n * n_local, DOUBLE, 0);
    //mbarimi i scattering-ut

    //Pjesa ku kryhet shumezimi
    for (int k = 0; k < n_local; k++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            matrix_c1[k][j] = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                matrix_c1[k][j] = matrix_c1[k][j] + matrix_a[k][i] * matrix_b[i][j];
        }

    //Mbledhja e rezultateve (Gathering) ne procesin zero
    MPI_COMM_WORLD.Gather(&matrix_c1, n * n_local, DOUBLE, &matrix_c, n * n_local, DOUBLE, 0);
    //mbarimi i gathering

    //Display area
    if (myrank == 0)
    {
        cout << "\n" << "REZULTATI: matrica c " << "\n";
        cout << "----------------" << "\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)cout << matrix_c[i][k] << "\t";
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

etc...

I have tried different editors but problem still, idk if i have forgotten any library.

Comment: you are using the MPI C++ bindings that have been removed from the MPI standard more than one decade ago, and I do not know if MS-MPI still provides them. Your best bet is to modernize your code and use the plain `C` bindings, or an other C++ish layer such as `Boost.MPI`

Comment: What if I try OpenMP?

Comment: if you meant `Open MPI`, the C++ bindings have been removed from recent releases. FWIW, you only have two lines to update.